# How to resolve extra margin added in formula field with multiple images?

Tags: formula, image-formula

Here's a sample formula field called Icons

```
IMAGE("/img/samples/color_red.gif", "Red",20,20) +
' ' +
IMAGE("/img/samples/color_yellow.gif", "yellow",20,20) +
' ' +
IMAGE("/img/samples/color_green.gif", "green",20,20)
```

When viewing the Icons field on the record detail page, the first image is not aligned with the rest of the icons.

[image]

When inspecting the field element in browser dev tools, it appears that an extra `margin-bottom: 0px;` is added by "default" in the style attribute of the **first** img tag (not sure why).

[image]

How to overcome this and remove the margin styling ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue [Formula (Text) Alignment Incorrect in details page](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V0000003wYVQAY), currently marked as NO FIX.

Found a workaround which can help resolving this:

Either add an extra image in the formula field with height and width set to 0 such that even if margin style is applied on this first image, it will not render at all.

Or add a white background image as first image so that it is transparent and does not affect display.

See result below of first option:

```
IMAGE("/img/samples/color_red.gif", 'None',0,0)  +
' ' +
IMAGE("/img/samples/color_red.gif", "Red",20,20) +
' ' +
IMAGE("/img/samples/color_yellow.gif", "yellow",20,20) +
' ' + 
IMAGE("/img/samples/color_green.gif", "green",20,20)
```

[image]

[image]